# How to generate random coordinates between two straights?

Tags: c, vector, random, coordinates

I have a vector with fixed coordinates, and given an increase in the Y axis (down and up) that determines me a region, I need to calculate random coordinates.[Image by the vector (black) coordinates and random coordinates (blue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzUyp.jpg)

I can generate a function to determinate the straights between the region i need to work. But i dont know how to generate random coordinates that belong to the region i need.

I'm looking for ideas for how to implement it.

Comment: If the distance between black and red lines is same for all values X you could try a very simple approach: Pick a random X. Calculate the corresponding Y value on the blue line. Pick a random offxet dY and add to the calculated Y on the line. Repeat for as many points you want. Sort points for ascending X values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `N` line segments and `N+1` points and your "straights" are defined as line segments between points `p[i]` and `p[i+1]` then you can do the following:

1. Randomly pick a line segment by choosing a point `i` between 0 and N (exclusive).
2. Randomly pick a number `a` between 0 and 1 that determines where along the line segment the new point will fall. Evaluate a new point `v = a*p[i] + (1-a)*p[i+1]`
3. Randomly pick some noise `y` between `ymin` and `ymax` (perhaps -2 to 2 or whatever your range is) and evaluate the new point `q=v+<0,y>`

If I understand what you are asking correctly, these `q` values are the points you are after.

If instead you are looking to generate random points subject to the least squares minimization of the line fitting those points is your black line, then that's a harder question I don't have time for right now.

Comment: Thanks for the help. No it is not squares minimization. It was the first that you say.
Solved. I solved it in a similar way as you raised it (I had not seen your answer). First I randomly determine an X in my range of values, then I evaluate that X  in two functions that I did to calculate the and Y_ Min and the and Y_ Max, then between those two I'm looking for a random Y value.